# Не опускается DIV вниз другого блока, float:bottom invalid property value

Tags: html, css, css3

Столкнулся с проблемой что не опускается блок вниз другого блока, а именно back-footer, float: bottom не работает, в отладчике показывает что invalid property value. Подскажите в чем причина? код прилагается.

```css
.wrap{
    
    width: 1480px;
    height: 1282px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: calc(50% - 1280px/2);
    top: calc(50% - 1480px/2);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header{
    position: relative;
    width: 1283px;
    height: 189px;
    margin: 61px 97px 50px 98px;
}
h1{
    margin: 0;
}
.h1 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 334px;
    height: 79px; 
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 94px;
    color: #000000;

}

.blue{
    color: #00e5ff;
}

/* .top-menu-fon ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1283px;
    height: 72px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 117px;
    background: #35444F;
}  */

ul.hr {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    margin: 0; /* Обнуляем значение отступов */
    text-align: center;
    width: 1283px;
    height: 72px;
    background: #35444F;
    padding:0;
   }
 ul.hr li {
    display: inline-block; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
    margin-right: 1px; /* Отступ слева */
   }

 .top{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding: 25px 30px 22px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
 
   }
 ul.hr li:hover{
    background: #222F3A;; /* Цвет фона под ссылкой */ 
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* Цвет ссылки */ 
   }
.body1{
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1283px;
    margin-left: 98px;
}

.left-menu{
    position: absolute;
    width: 344px;
    height: 399px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    /* margin: 0px 52px 484px 0px; */
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 28px auto;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.hv li {
    display: inline-block; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 26.9932px;
    line-height: 80px;
    
   }

 .left{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding: 25px 44px 22px;
    color: #495863;
 
   }
   ul li:hover{
    background: #DBDBDB; 
    color: #35444F;
   
   }
   .left:hover{
    margin-left: 30px;
    transition: 1s;
   }

.content{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 885px;
    height: 832px;
}
.top-img-fon{
    width: 885px;
    height: 529px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

p{
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.img{
    width: 320px;
    height: 381px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 74px;
    background-image: url(../img/top.png);
    transition: 1s;
}
    
   .img:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    }

    footer{


    }

    .back-footer{
        float: bottom;
        width: 1284px;
        height: 69px;
        margin-left:98px;
        background: rgba(99, 105, 110, 0.48);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Ramda.js</title>
</head>
<body style="background: #E5E5E5;">
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="header">
        <h1 class="h1 a"><a href="#" target="_blank">Ra<span class='blue'>mda.js</span></a></h1>
   
        <div class="top-menu-fon">
               <ul class="hr">
                   <li><a href="#" class="top">Functional programming</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" class="top">Ramba</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" class="top">Fantasy Land Spec</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" class="top">Node.js for all</a></li>
               </ul> 
        </div>
        
    </div>
        <div class="body1">

        
            <div class="left-menu">
            <ul class="ul.hv">
                <li><a href="#" class="left">Ramda</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="left">Why Ramda?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="left">What`s Different?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="left">Introduction</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="left">Philosoph</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
            <div class="top-img-fon">
                <div class="img"></div>
            </div>
            <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod </p>        

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back-footer">


        </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: да и bottom: 30px пробовал, просто идей нету, подскажите добрые люди

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrap {
  width: 1480px;
  height: 1282px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: calc(50% - 1280px/2);
  top: calc(50% - 1480px/2);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 1283px;
  height: 189px;
  margin: 61px 97px 50px 98px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 334px;
  height: 79px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 94px;
  color: #000000;
}

.blue {
  color: #00e5ff;
}


/* .top-menu-fon ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1283px;
    height: 72px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 117px;
    background: #35444F;
}  */

ul.hr {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  /* Обнуляем значение отступов */
  text-align: center;
  width: 1283px;
  height: 72px;
  background: #35444F;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.hr li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
  margin-right: 1px;
  /* Отступ слева */
}

.top {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 25px 30px 22px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.hr li:hover {
  background: #222F3A;
  ;
  /* Цвет фона под ссылкой */
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* Цвет ссылки */
}

.body1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1283px;
  margin-left: 98px;
}

.left-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 344px;
  height: 399px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* margin: 0px 52px 484px 0px; */
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 28px auto;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.hv li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 26.9932px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.left {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 25px 44px 22px;
  color: #495863;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #DBDBDB;
  color: #35444F;
}

.left:hover {
  margin-left: 30px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 885px;
  height: 832px;
}

.top-img-fon {
  width: 885px;
  height: 529px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.img {
  width: 320px;
  height: 381px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 74px;
  background-image: url(../img/top.png);
  transition: 1s;
}

.img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
}

footer {}

.back-footer {
  width: 1284px;
  height: 69px;
  margin-left: 98px;
  background: rgba(99, 105, 110, 0.48);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="h1 a"><a href="#" target="_blank">Ra<span class='blue'>mda.js</span></a></h1>
    <div class="top-menu-fon">
      <ul class="hr">
        <li><a href="#" class="top">Functional programming</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="top">Ramba</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="top">Fantasy Land Spec</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="top">Node.js for all</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body1">
    <div class="left-menu">
      <ul class="ul.hv">
        <li><a href="#" class="left">Ramda</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="left">Why Ramda?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="left">What`s Different?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="left">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="left">Philosoph</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="top-img-fon">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="back-footer">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, так и должно быть, только не могу заметить какую правку Вы внесли